# Prevent context menu and mouse drag on all elements but one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent right click context menu, and mouse drag on every element on my page except for one called 'IPAddress'.

Using the code below would seem to do the job, but I still cannot select the element 'IPAddress'.

How can this be altered to allow for this behavior?

```
html.on('selectstart dragstart contextmenu', function (evt) { // prevent right click, and mouse drag
    if (html.not('#IPAddress')) {
        evt.preventDefault(); return false;
    };
});
```

Comment: Not an answer, just thanking you as a new user for taking the time to format your code properly and do your research before asking a question.

Comment: Thank-you. Glad to have a place like this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!$(evt.target).is('#IPAddress'))
```

jQuery [not](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/) is intended for elements-set filtering, and is not the opposite of [is](http://api.jquery.com/%3ais/).

Comment: That did it! Never would have thought of that.